# Получение названия процесса из обратного вызова в драйвере

Tags: c++, драйвер, kernel

есть такая проблемка.... Есть драйвер регистрирующий обратные вызовы на создание процесса. Мне нужно отследить, что работник запустил определенный процесс, скажем notepad.exe, как это можно сделать? пробовал в функции обратного вызова:

```
 if (PsGetProcessImageFileName(PsGetCurrentProcess()) == "notepad.exe")
  {
    DbgPrint("nashli");
  };
```

не работает((( хотя PsGetProcessImageFileName тип PCHAR

Comment: `==` в данном случае сравнивает указатели

Comment: каким образом было бы грамотнее написать?

Comment: [`strcmp()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp)

Answer (score -2):

`==` в данном случае сравнивает указатели

[strcmp()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp)